# How to get HTML response of each multistore page?

Tags: multistore, ce-1.9.0.1

there.

I want to get HTML response of my magento shop page.

So I coded a small PHP program for this with using CURL library(and I tried also with file_get_contents());

```
$crl = curl_init();
$timeout = 10;
curl_setopt($crl, CURLPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$response = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);
```

At first glance, it works well. But I found one problem.

My shop has 2 multilingual store. 
So I tried 2 urls.
"http://MYSHOP.COM/TARGET_PAGE/?___store=default&___from_store=french" and "http://MYSHOP.COM/TARGET_PAGE/?___store=french&___from_store=default"

However the both returns are same. they return always 'default' store result.
When I open these urls on my browser, they shows right result with each language. Why is it caused?

I guess it might be related with some cookie issue. how can I get the right result?

PS. I searched browser cookies with developer tools of Chrome, but I could not find any suspicious cookies which might be related with language info.

Comment: Have you tried to add session support for curl request?

Comment: I need more information about that. What kind of session support??

Comment: Have added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"); 
$cookie_file = "cookie1.txt";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);`
```

Also, try to you add URL params using separate curl  function, not just as a part of the link

Comment: Also, what is about just file_get_contents?

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
I tried file_get_contents function instead of curl. :D

Comment: I'll try some hours later (sorry, I must finish other works before this), and I'll report the result. and I will accept wheter it works or not. :) Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, 
At first, I failed with your code. Frankly said, I cannot understand How it works. But I got a hint from your codes. 

I tried additional code. That is ridiculous simple.

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);

It works fine. Thanks your help.